# How to use ID2D1SpriteBatch in SharpDX?

Tags: c#, sharpdx, direct2d, spritebatch

Trying to make use of ID2D1SpriteBatch in direct2d to get performance boost over the regular DrawBitmap().

Managed to set it up but i get "The object was not in the correct state to process the method" when i call DeviceContext.EndDraw().

I can get the DeviceContext.DrawBitmap() to work (see commented out section). Tried everything i can think to get the device context in the right state to handle the spritebatch but no luck.

Tried to boil this sample down as much as possible but also didn't want to leave out any step just in case that was the culprit.

Any ideas how to get it to work?

```
using SharpDX;
using _d2d = SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using _d3d = SharpDX.Direct3D;
using _d3d11 = SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using _dxgi = SharpDX.DXGI;
using _directWrite = SharpDX.DirectWrite;
using _wic = SharpDX.WIC;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Windows;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharpDX.IO;
using SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class SpriteBatchIssue
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new SpriteBatchIssue();
            app.Run();
        }

        bool isClosed = false;

        public void Run()
        {
            #region setup resources      
            var clientSize = new Size2(1000, 500);

            var mainForm = new RenderForm();
            mainForm.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(
                clientSize.Width,
                clientSize.Height);

            mainForm.FormClosed += mainForm_FormClosed;

            var scDescription = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                BufferCount = 1,
                ModeDescription =
                    new ModeDescription(
                        clientSize.Width,
                        clientSize.Height,
                        new Rational(60, 1),
                        Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
                IsWindowed = true,
                OutputHandle = mainForm.Handle,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };

            // Create Device and SwapChain
            _d3d11.Device d3d11Device;
            SwapChain swapChain;
            _d3d11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(
                DriverType.Hardware,
                DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport,
                new[] { _d3d.FeatureLevel.Level_12_1 },
                scDescription,
                out d3d11Device,
                out swapChain);

            // Ignore all windows events
            var dxgiFactory = swapChain.GetParent<_dxgi.Factory1>();
            dxgiFactory.MakeWindowAssociation(mainForm.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

            // New RenderTargetView from the backbuffer
            var backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);
            var backBufferView = new RenderTargetView(d3d11Device, backBuffer);

            var d2dFactory = new _d2d.Factory();
            var d2dFactory4 = d2dFactory.QueryInterface<_d2d.Factory4>();

            var dxgiDevice = d3d11Device.QueryInterface<_dxgi.Device>();
            var d2dDevice3 = new _d2d.Device3(d2dFactory4, dxgiDevice);
            var d2dDeviceContext3 = new _d2d.DeviceContext3(d2dDevice3, DeviceContextOptions.None);

            using (var surface = backBuffer.QueryInterface<Surface>())
            {
                var bmpProperties = new BitmapProperties1(
                    new PixelFormat(Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, _d2d.AlphaMode.Premultiplied),
                    dpiX: 96,
                    dpiY: 96,
                    bitmapOptions: BitmapOptions.Target | BitmapOptions.CannotDraw);

                var d2dTarget = new Bitmap1(
                    d2dDeviceContext3,
                    surface,
                    bmpProperties);

                d2dDeviceContext3.Target = d2dTarget;
            }
            #endregion

            #region setup drawing parameters
            var bmp = createD2DBitmap(@"C:\yourPath\yourImage.png", d2dDeviceContext3);

            var spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(d2dDeviceContext3);
            var destinationRects = new RawRectangleF[1];
            destinationRects[0] = new RectangleF(100, 50, bmp.Size.Width, bmp.Size.Height);

            var sourceRects = new RawRectangle[1];
            sourceRects[0] = new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Size.Width, bmp.Size.Height);

            var colors = new RawColor4[1];
            colors[0] = Color.White;

            var transforms = new RawMatrix3x2[1];
            transforms[0] = Matrix3x2.Identity;
            #endregion

            #region mainLoop
            RenderLoop.Run(mainForm, () =>
            {
                if (isClosed)
                {
                    return;
                }

                d3d11Device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.SetViewport(new Viewport(0, 0, clientSize.Width, clientSize.Height));
                d3d11Device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(backBufferView);

                d2dDeviceContext3.BeginDraw();

                //this technique works
                //d2dDeviceContext3.DrawBitmap(
                //    bitmap: bmp,
                //    destinationRectangle: destinationRects[0],
                //    opacity: 1,
                //    interpolationMode: BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear,
                //    sourceRectangle: new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Size.Width, bmp.Size.Height));

                //this technique does not work
                spriteBatch.Clear();
                spriteBatch.AddSprites(
                    1,
                    destinationRects,
                    sourceRects,
                    colors,
                    transforms,
                    destinationRectanglesStride: 0, //0 stride because there is only 1 element
                    sourceRectanglesStride: 0, //i've also tried using Marshal.SizeOf() to get the stride, but i get the same error
                    colorsStride: 0,
                    transformsStride: 0);

                d2dDeviceContext3.DrawSpriteBatch(
                    spriteBatch: spriteBatch,
                    startIndex: 0,
                    spriteCount: 1,
                    bitmap: bmp,
                    interpolationMode: BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear,
                    spriteOptions: SpriteOptions.ClampToSourceRectangle);

                //when using the spritebatch technique, this throws exception:
                // "The object was not in the correct state to process the method"
                d2dDeviceContext3.EndDraw();

                //first param set to 1 would indicate waitVerticalBlanking
                swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
            });
            #endregion
        }

        Bitmap createD2DBitmap(string filePath, _d2d.DeviceContext deviceContext)
        {
            var imagingFactory = new _wic.ImagingFactory();

            var fileStream = new NativeFileStream(
                filePath,
                NativeFileMode.Open,
                NativeFileAccess.Read);

            var bitmapDecoder = new _wic.BitmapDecoder(imagingFactory, fileStream, _wic.DecodeOptions.CacheOnDemand);
            var frame = bitmapDecoder.GetFrame(0);

            var converter = new _wic.FormatConverter(imagingFactory);
            converter.Initialize(frame, SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPRGBA);

            var newBitmap = SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap1.FromWicBitmap(deviceContext, converter);

            return newBitmap;
        }

        void mainForm_FormClosed(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            isClosed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that you can't use per primitive antialiasing with a spritebatch. This line before BeginDraw() fixed it: d2dDeviceContext3.AntialiasMode = AntialiasMode.Aliased;

Also learned finally how to get the debug layer working. Include debug flag when creating your device (see comments below). If it throws an exception, that is probably because you dont have the right version of windows sdk. If you're using visual studio, go to visual studio installer and modify your installation to include windows sdk.

Next you need to right click your project->properties->debug (on the left panel)-> check "enable native code debugging". After i did this there was a line written to the output window stating: "D2D DEBUG ERROR - DrawSpriteBatch requires that the antialias mode be set to D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_ALIASED."

Something else i learned that isn't directly related to the answer but worth noting: "Note that ComObject in SharpDX is not disposed by the .NET finalizer. If a COM object is not released by a call to Dispose() or ReleaseReference(), it will not release the native object and memory attached to it." from here: http://sharpdx.org/wiki/usage/

Here's a full working example:

```
using SharpDX;
using _d2d = SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using _d3d = SharpDX.Direct3D;
using _d3d11 = SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using _dxgi = SharpDX.DXGI;
using _directWrite = SharpDX.DirectWrite;
using _wic = SharpDX.WIC;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Windows;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharpDX.IO;
using SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class SpriteBatchIssue
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new SpriteBatchIssue();
            app.Run();
        }

        #region Variables
        _d3d11.Device d3d11Device;
        SwapChain swapChain;
        _dxgi.Factory1 dxgiFactory;
        _d2d.Factory d2dFactory;
        _d2d.Factory4 d2dFactory4;

        _dxgi.Device dxgiDevice;
        _d2d.Device3 d2dDevice3;
        _d2d.DeviceContext3 d2dDeviceContext3;

        Bitmap1 sourceImage;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Bitmap1 d2dTarget;
        #endregion

        ~SpriteBatchIssue()
        {
            safeDispose(ref d3d11Device);
            safeDispose(ref swapChain);
            safeDispose(ref dxgiFactory);
            safeDispose(ref d2dFactory);
            safeDispose(ref d2dFactory4);
            safeDispose(ref dxgiDevice);
            safeDispose(ref d2dDevice3);
            safeDispose(ref d2dDeviceContext3);
            safeDispose(ref sourceImage);
            safeDispose(ref spriteBatch);
            safeDispose(ref d2dTarget);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            #region setup resources      
            var mainForm = new RenderForm();

            var scDescription = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                BufferCount = 1,
                ModeDescription =
                    new ModeDescription(
                        0,
                        0,
                        new Rational(60, 1),
                        Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
                IsWindowed = true,
                OutputHandle = mainForm.Handle,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };

            //DeviceCreationFlags.Debug flag below will show debug layer messages in your output window.
            //Need proper version of windows sdk for it to work, otherwise it will throw an exception.
            //You also need to right click your project->properties->debug (on the left panel)-> check "enable native code debugging"

            // Create Device and SwapChain
            _d3d11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(
                DriverType.Hardware,
                DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport | DeviceCreationFlags.Debug, 
                new[] { _d3d.FeatureLevel.Level_12_1 },
                scDescription,
                out d3d11Device,
                out swapChain);

            // Ignore all windows events
            dxgiFactory = swapChain.GetParent<_dxgi.Factory1>();
            dxgiFactory.MakeWindowAssociation(mainForm.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

            d2dFactory = new _d2d.Factory();
            d2dFactory4 = d2dFactory.QueryInterface<_d2d.Factory4>();

            dxgiDevice = d3d11Device.QueryInterface<_dxgi.Device>();
            d2dDevice3 = new _d2d.Device3(d2dFactory4, dxgiDevice);
            d2dDeviceContext3 = new _d2d.DeviceContext3(d2dDevice3, DeviceContextOptions.None);
            #endregion

            #region create drawing input
            sourceImage = createD2DBitmap(@"yourFile.png", d2dDeviceContext3);

            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(d2dDeviceContext3);
            var destinationRects = new RawRectangleF[1];
            destinationRects[0] = new RectangleF(100, 50, sourceImage.Size.Width, sourceImage.Size.Height);

            var sourceRects = new RawRectangle[1];
            sourceRects[0] = new RectangleF(0, 0, sourceImage.Size.Width, sourceImage.Size.Height);
            #endregion

            #region mainLoop
            RenderLoop.Run(mainForm, () =>
            {
                if (d2dTarget != null)
                {
                    d2dTarget.Dispose();
                    d2dTarget = null;
                }

                using (var backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0))
                {
                    using (var surface = backBuffer.QueryInterface<Surface>())
                    {
                        var bmpProperties = new BitmapProperties1(
                            new PixelFormat(Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, _d2d.AlphaMode.Premultiplied),
                            dpiX: 96,
                            dpiY: 96,
                            bitmapOptions: BitmapOptions.Target | BitmapOptions.CannotDraw);

                        d2dTarget = new Bitmap1(
                            d2dDeviceContext3,
                            surface,
                            bmpProperties);

                        d2dDeviceContext3.Target = d2dTarget;
                    }
                }

                //the key missing piece: cannot use per primitive antialiasing with spritebatch
                d2dDeviceContext3.AntialiasMode = AntialiasMode.Aliased;
                d2dDeviceContext3.BeginDraw();

                spriteBatch.Clear();
                spriteBatch.AddSprites(
                    1,
                    destinationRects,
                    sourceRects,
                    null,
                    null,
                    destinationRectanglesStride: 0, //0 stride because there is only 1 element
                    sourceRectanglesStride: 0,
                    colorsStride: 0,
                    transformsStride: 0);

                d2dDeviceContext3.DrawSpriteBatch(
                    spriteBatch: spriteBatch,
                    startIndex: 0,
                    spriteCount: 1,
                    bitmap: sourceImage,
                    interpolationMode: BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear,
                    spriteOptions: SpriteOptions.ClampToSourceRectangle);

                d2dDeviceContext3.EndDraw();

                //first param set to 1 would indicate waitVerticalBlanking
                swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
            });
            #endregion
        }

        void safeDispose<T>(ref T disposable) where T : class, IDisposable
        {
            if (disposable != null)
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
                disposable = null;
            }
        }

        Bitmap1 createD2DBitmap(string filePath, _d2d.DeviceContext deviceContext)
        {
            var imagingFactory = new _wic.ImagingFactory();

            var fileStream = new NativeFileStream(
                filePath,
                NativeFileMode.Open,
                NativeFileAccess.Read);

            var bitmapDecoder = new _wic.BitmapDecoder(imagingFactory, fileStream, _wic.DecodeOptions.CacheOnDemand);
            var frame = bitmapDecoder.GetFrame(0);

            var converter = new _wic.FormatConverter(imagingFactory);
            converter.Initialize(frame, SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPRGBA);

            var newBitmap = SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap1.FromWicBitmap(deviceContext, converter);

            return newBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you see a bright green box around everything you draw, that could be from d2d.factory construction option. If you use DebugLevel.Information there, it will add bright green to everything i guess as a debug vis.